# Add-On CD Formula

Tags: investing, calculation, interest

I'm starting to learn a lot about finance/investing on my own but I'm struggling with the calculations behind Add-On CDs. I opened an 14-Month Add-On CD with a $1000 deposit with a monthly $30 add-on awhile ago and it's soon to mature.

I already **"A=P(1+r/n)^nt"** but... I just can't seem to formulate something regarding this.

What would be the formula?